# catch up SQLite error "database is locked"

Tags: php, sql, sqlite

i am opening an SQLiteDB with following statement in PHP what is working well.

```
$db2 = new SQLite3("/home/pi/ion.sqb", SQLITE3_OPEN_READONLY);
$resu2 = $db2->query("select * from test where name = 'Hans'");
```

however from time to time i am running into following error message :: SQLite is locked and the PHP-script kills itself with following fatal message:

```
PHP Warning:  SQLite3::query(): Unable to execute statement: database is locked in /home/pi/ion.sqb on line 559
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function fetchArray() on boolean in /home/pi/dbc.php:560
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
  thrown in /home/pi/dbc.php on line 560
```

I tried to check if the DB is locked and skip the select ... however without success:

```
$db2 = new SQLite3("/home/pi/ion.sqb", SQLITE3_OPEN_READONLY);
$resu2 = $db2->query("select * from test where name = 'Hans'");
if (!$db2) {
    echo "DB DB-locked";
    }
else{ 
    $resu2 = $db2->query("select * from test where name = 'Hans'");
    while ($dsatz2 = $resu2->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC))
  ...
```

the issue that you can run into a logged SQLite DB is known .. 
also for a select, when any other handle is in write-mode.

how can i circumstanced that my script runs into that fatal error and ends itself?

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function fetchArray() on boolean in /home/pi/dbc.php:560
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
  thrown in /home/pi/dbc.php on line 560
```

Comment: Use a database that can actually handle concurrency, eg: mariadb, postgres. You're not going to be able to work around this in a way that is sane or performant.

Answer (score 1):

This is a contingency problem. The sqlite spec clearly states that in a multi-process (which PHP is, if multiple requests hit the file at the same time) or multi-threaded environment, if two `SELECT` queries concurrently hit the same table, the "later" one will get this error.

Unfortunately, when dealing with this issue in PHP, you don't have many options at your disposal. I don't even think you can enable the shared cache in an environment that ends at the end of a request, so even that is out of the window.

Honestly, I'd suggest a microtime sleep (say, half the time of your usual `SELECT` duration) and a retry in this case.

Comment: thanks Sebastien - do I understand you correct, that during my "if" it is not yet locked but that milli_sec later while my "$resu2->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC))" ..?
... so a sleep could help?

Comment: a sleep-retry might help, yes, but ultimately it's only delaying the inevitable. The fact of the matter is that sqlite doesn't really scale up that well vs. number of requests.

Comment: Sebastien - may i ask you if you see any method to catch the error message within my PHP skript?
my " if (!$db2) ... " does not work.

Answer (score 0):

A late answer I'm afraid.

1. Set the timeout for how long to wait for a locked database.

E.g. before running any queries:

```
$db2->busyTimeout(250);
```

See: https://www.php.net/manual/en/sqlite3.busytimeout.php

2. Use [WAL](https://www.sqlite.org/wal.html) (available since sqlite 3.7) for improved concurrency.

E.g. After instantiation

```
$db2->exec('PRAGMA journal_mode = wal;');
```